# Prevent users in a network from changing file permissions using Nautilus

Tags: file, permissions, fedora

How to prevent the users (students) in a network from changing the file permissions using the Nautilus in Fedora? I am able to block the use of chmod command.
A student in the network, after having written a code for a programming assignment give RWX permissions through Nautilus, so their friends could copy (who are in the same network with a different login-id).